# jquery ui slider image width

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I'm trying to make an image appear as the slider moves. So for example I have 2 images and the one images has overflow:hidden and width:0%. So when I move the slider the 1st image must increase its width over the 2nd image.

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="puppy"><img src="images/dog.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="kitten"><img src="images/cat.jpg" /></div>

    <div id="slider"></div>
</body>
```

Here is my JS

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider();
});
```

And here is my css

```
.puppy {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
}
```

And here is the JSFIDDLE: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cerberus478/92ytK/4/)

If there is anything that isn't clear please let me know

Comment: I have managed to get what I need working. Here is the working version: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/92ytK/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach change of width of *puppy* image to scrolling of slider. And you have not done this.

I have used this for changing of content of form for number of images per line in gallery

```
$( "#Slider" ).slider({
    value: $( "#ImagesNumber" ).val(),
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#ImagesNumber" ).val( ui.value );
    }
});
```

where:

```
value: $( "#ImagesNumber" ).val(),
```

sets initial number

```
min: 1,
```

sets the least number

```
max: 10,
```

sets the highest number

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {$( "#ImagesNumber" ).val( ui.value );}
```

ties change of number to scrolling of slider.

In your case it would be:

```
$( "#Slider" ).slider({
    value: $( ".puppy" ).css('width'),
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( ".puppy" ).css('width', ui.value );
    }
});
```

I suggest 100 in meaning of 100% - because it is a little better for case if images would have various size in pixels (of course, I suppose that initially visible and initially hidden images have the same size). So you would need to do additional counting to convert percents to pixels.

I only would suggest to erase absolute position and hidden overflow from your css, unless it is absolutely positioned in whole text - and it is have very limited space to show. Then you may let absolute position and hidden overflow in your css.

And if you would like to show *puppy* and hide *kitten* as slider scrolls, you would do additional counting of widths too.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/92ytK/14/).

Set one picture as the background to a div, the other picture in the div and vary the width with the slider.

JS

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
                       value: 1,
                         min: 1,
                         max: 100,
                        step: 1,
                       slide: function( event, ui ) {
                                                     $( "#slidevalue" ).html( ui.value );
                                                     $('#mydog').css('width', (ui.value * 4) );
                                                     }
                       });
```